# Display Macros on a Microsoft Keyboard?

Tags: windows-8, macros, intellitype

I am using IntelliType Pro (v8.2) with a Sidewinder X4 keyboard. Is there a way I can display the macro names and assigned macro keys on screen?

For instance if I press a macro key that is not assigned I see this message in the lower left of my screen:

[image: Macro Screenshot]

What I am looking for is the same type of message but it displays my assigned macros for the bank and program I am in.

Update: A recent update from Microsoft has changed IntelliType. I no longer see IntelliType, I see `Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center`. The looks are completely different, however, the functionality is exactly the same from what I can tell. (Looks like they have redone Intellitype to fit more with Windows 8 and re-named the program.)

Note: I am on Windows 8.